# Namespace, folders and classes in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, namespaces

I have a solution with about four projects in them. A main or startup project and child projects. The startup project is basically the MDI form which has the menus and the child projects are called from this main project menus. In this wise, the main MDI project has references from the child projects. For instance, in the MDI reference folder are the following child projects dlls, Business.child.DAL, Business.child.Views, Business.child.BL, Business.child.BI.
Now in the MDI

```
using Business.child.DAL
using Business.child.Views
using Business.child.BL
using Business.child.BI
```

Now what is happening is, the BL and BI are not coming up when you type using  Buinsess.child...., the BL and BI does not appear. So the classes in the BL is not accessible now. I can't figure out what is happening and I need help here. 
Thanks good people.

Comment: are BL and BI namespaces or classes?? if there are classes you cant reference them

Comment: A using is no reference to something. You have referenced the mentioned assemblies correctly?

Comment: They are folders. DAL contains DataSets, Views contains windows forms, BL contains classes and BI contains Reports.  The name space is Business.child.  I am able to access the forms in the views folder and alos able to access the dataset and adapters in the DAL folder from the main MDI project

Comment: Awww! Just got it. I just needed to make the class I want public.  Thank you good people.

Answer (score 0):

What I realize was that, the class 'businessproperties' needed to be made public. After making it public class businessproperties the BL folder was now visible in the main MDI app.

```
using business.child.BL
```

I am able to now have the reference.